# Java: Can't convert string to array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, text

I can't convert a string to an array!

```
String text = "";
String[] textsplit = {};

//Stuff
```

The app set the content of an online txt file in a string:

The online txt file contain: hello,my,name,is,simone

```
[...] //Downloading code
text = bo.toString(); //Set the content of the online file to the string
```

Now the string text is like this:

```
text = "hello,my,name,is,simone"
```

Now i have to convert the string to an array that must be like this:

```
textsplit = {"hello","my","name","is","simone"}
```

so the code that i use is:

```
textsplit = text.split(",");
```

But when i try to use the array the app crash! :(
For example:

```
textview.setText(textsplit[0]); //The text of the textview is empity
textview.setText(textsplit[1]); //The app crash
textview.setText(textsplit[2]); //The app crash
```

etc...
where am I wrong? thanks!

EDIT: This is the code:

```
new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String path ="http://www.luconisimone.altervista.org/ciao.txt";
            URL u = null;
            try {
                u = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.connect();
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
                bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        text = bo.toString();
                        testo.setText("(" + text + ")");
                        try {
                            bo.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }.start();

// Here all variables became empity


    textsplit = text.split(",");
    datisplittati.setText(textsplit[0]);
```

Comment: I do not see anything wrong. Are you absolutely sure `text` is the String you provided? The fact that the first element of the array is empty would suggest that the String is empty since `"".split(",");` would be an array with a single empty String object

Comment: You need to print the text that is received from the file and ensure that its contents is as expected. Also, **Arrays.toString(textsplit)** will return a readable String representation of the array contents, which you can use to print for debugging.

Comment: Your string is like "hello,my,name,is,simone" or  "hello, my, name, is, simone"?

Please paste string here same like you pass

Comment: @SamTebbs33 or better would be to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: You can trim string before splitting. And then try I think your problem will solved

Comment: I found the problem but do not know how to fix it! The command that set the String text with the content of the online txt file is it inside a thread, but outside of the thread the string became empity! So when i call the command split it split an empity string. How to fix it?

Comment: Paste your code here

Comment: I paste the code in the main question

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
String text = "hello,my,name,is,simone";
String[] textArr = text.split(Pattern.quote(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get string using AsyncTask

```
private class GetStringFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog ;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // show progress dialog when downloading 
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Downloading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // @BadSkillz codes with same changes
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");
            }
            String result = total.toString();
            Log.i("Get URL", "Downloaded string: " + result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Get Url", "Error in downloading: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // TODO change text view id for yourself
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // show result in textView
        if (result == null) {
            textView.setText("Error in downloading. Please try again.");
        } else {
            textView.setText(result);
        }

        // close progresses dialog
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and use blow line every time that you want:

```
new GetStringFromUrl().execute("http://www.luconisimone.altervista.org/ciao.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using new thread to get data from an url. So in runtime, data will be asynchronous. 
So when you access *text* variable (split it), it's still not get full value (example reason: network delay). 
Try to move the function split after  *text = bo.toString();* , I think it will work well.